# How to debug checkout_cart_product_add_after event on exit

Tags: cart, event-observer, magento2.3, addtocart

I am trying to exit point on observer for `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event.

But it always refresh after item added to cart.

Any way to print data when debug this event and not refresh the page.

It happen when i print or echo something.it works with log file but everytime i have to check log so it would be easy if i can check it with exit on code.

Comment: No but i want to use only `checkout_cart_product_add_after ` event not other